# Is possible imite ngrok or copie it and mount in server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ngrok

It is possible make my service that equal to ngrok or make one ngrok of cero.

I have one server with ip public and my idea is mount it in server.

For the moment , nothing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Of course, my intention is to be able to replicate all the functionality that ngrok does, I understand that it works with ssl and other things, my idea is to imitate as much as possible on an aws server and so when you want to view a page, do it from my own server and generate a temporary domain and not depend on ngrok, I don't know if I'm explaining myself, practically it would be to imitate ngrok as much as possible or at least get to the point where it allows me to deploy the redirection through my aws server and enter by a temporary dns that is created.

Comment: Practically make a wormhole and be able to redirect it to a port and obviously give me a dns to enter or, failing that, enter with the public IP of the aws server and the port.